# if statement with getelementbyclass

Tags: vba, if-statement, getelementsbyclassname

First off, I am relatively new to programming. I have been making myself familiar primarily with VBA. I have asked questions here before and so far the responses have been very helpful so I am trying my luck again.

I am going to this site: http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock-screener

I want my script to say something like:

```
if ElementClassName("listingOdd").innertext = "USA, NV"
then GetElementsbyClassName("listingOddlistingOdd whiteSpaceNormal").innertext
```

I would also like it to loop through and click the next button which is behind this html until it is completed : 
    a href="javascript:void(null);">next & gt;/a

Any help is welcomed, I have been searching through past questions and watching tutorials and would not be asking if I was not seriously banging my head on this one. Thanks a lot in advance

This is some code that I have tried, with the following error: "Object doesnt support this method" 
There is a lot commented out from trial and error

```
Sub t()


Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False

IE.navigate "http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock-screener"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.document
Dim sDD As String
Dim lnk As Variant
sDD = Trim(Doc.GetElementbyClassName("listingOddlistingOdd whiteSpaceNormal").innerText)
'If lnk.classame.innerText = "USA, NV" Then
If lnk.innerText = "USA, NV" Then
'If ElementClassName("listingOdd")(0).innerText = "USA, NV" Then
'sDD
'sDD = Trim(Doc.GetElementbyClassName("listingOddlistingOdd whiteSpaceNormal").innerText)
MsgBox sDD
End If




End Sub
```

Sorry for the spaghetti code, like I said I am new

Comment: `getElementsByClassName`  Post some actual code you've tried, and state what error(s) you get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really clear on exactly what you're trying to get (and why not just use the handy "download all" link at the top of the page?)

**EDITED** - place cell values on worksheet
**EDIT2** - clicking the "next" link.
**EDIT3** - looped

This kind of thing is a total rabbit hole though.

```
Sub Tester()
Dim doc As Object
Dim IE As Object, nxt
Dim rng As Range, x As Integer

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2")
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock-screener"
    WaitForLoad IE

    Set nxt = GetNext(IE)
    Do While Not nxt Is Nothing
        ExtractTableContent IE, rng
        nxt.Click
        WaitForLoad IE
        Set nxt = GetNext(IE)
    Loop
End Sub

Sub WaitForLoad(IE As Object)
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.readyState = 4 'READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
End Sub
'copy table content
Sub ExtractTableContent(ByRef IE As Object, ByRef rng As Range)
    Dim tableDiv As Object, r As Object, rw As Object, x As Long

    Set tableDiv = IE.document.getelementbyid("stockScreenerResults")
    Set r = tableDiv.getelementsbytagname("table")(0).Rows
    For Each rw In r
        For x = 1 To rw.Cells.Length
            rng.Offset(0, x - 1).Value = rw.Cells(x - 1).innerText
        Next x
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Next rw
End Sub

'find the link which takes you to the next page...
Function GetNext(IE As Object) As Object
    Dim links, l As Object, rv As Object, cn As Object
    Set links = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
    For Each l In links
       If l.innerText Like "*next*" Then
        Set rv = l
        Exit For
       End If
    Next l
    Set GetNext = rv
End Function
```

Comment: The problem with the download link provided is that it does not give me the ability to restrict results to nevada only, which gives me incomplete results since it limits me to 2000 search results. I did try that first. Thanks for your patience and time in answering. I give you the credit =) Thanks again

Comment: At the risk of sounding ignorant, I am not getting any results printed to the cells in my spreadsheet

Comment: `Debug.Print` prints in the Debug window, not in the spreadsheet.

Comment: That was just to illustrate a possible different approach to your `getElementsbyClassname`. I will edit to put the results in a worksheet...

Comment: Thanks you guys, I feel silly for sure. It is a steep learning curve in the begining. This will hopefully be the last question, but how do I get it to select the next button so I can get all results and not just the A's. FYI - no i do not want just the odd rows, another mistake on my part. I am red in the face for sure. You guys are very helpful thankyou, especially you Tim

Comment: Actually I think I can figure it out, I am falling into the trap of over handicapping myself. If I had the reputation points I would vote you up more good sir.

Comment: If you dont mind, I am having a hard time with this loop. The closest I have gotten is "Do while Not nxt is nothing", which gives me an overflow error @TimWilliams

Comment: I would not ask if I havnt been working on it for 6 hours straight

Comment: Okay, I got it to loop through the next commands, but when I try to set my do until earlier it says object not set. I am making progress now though so I am not so frusterated

Comment: See updated code.  This may well violate the usage terms of the site, so be mindful of that.

Comment: Thank you so much man. I didnt realize I was possibly in violation of the sites terms. If it wasnt such a necessity I wouldve spent a week or two on it. I am done commenting here. I assure you I will do ALL my homework before I ask a question on here. You are the man!